# Deleted question

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-answers

I have asked a question about socket:
[What exactly is Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233193/what-exactly-is-socket/16233249?iemail=1&noredirect=1#16233249)

When I get the answer, I have asked the sub-question about socket - is the protocol the one who defines its type or something else. My question was:
"
Thank you. I didn't know it is a file. And different sockets have just different info and different api, depends on protocol the connection is using(ip, udp, tcp, http,...) or it depends on something else, since we have raw socket, web socket,....
"
But obvious I didn't asked the right way since Gordon has deleted my second question(answer).
What would be the appropriate form of my second question? Should I asked the second question as new thread? I have read the rules but I'm still confused :)
Otherwise I like this portal and i would like to follow the rules.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you know the difference between "question" and "answer"? Your **answer** was deleted because it wasn't an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Don't ask a question as an answer. If you have any doubt in the given answer then use comment to ask related question. If you have separate question then ask it as a new question.

Comment: Or, if the question is a genuinely separate one, sparked by the answer: ask a separate question and possibly link to the original one for further information. But make sure that the new answer is self-contained.

Comment: It wasn't even a question, it was a comment at best. I see you have <10K rep so here is a copy: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8GedQ.png

Comment: Someone has for example original question: What is the socket?
Then he gets an answer.
Then the second question would be: What are the socket types?

One possible option I can see is also to change the original question, since you can edit it, to be:
What is the socket and what are it's types?

But that is probably not the right way. What would be the most appropriate way:
Add a new comment with the new question about the types below the original question?
Add a new question?
Since it is in some way only the expansion of the original one, I would rather do as the new comment.

Comment: "Sha Wiz Dow Ard" - Yes, I forgot to add a question mark on the end of the comment - than it would be the question. I apologize for that.

Yes, my rep is low. But I'll try to raise it. Maybe also with answering some question from the area I'm most familiar with.

Comment: @Simon - As already said if the second question is separate one then ask it separately. If it is related to the first one and it's answer is probably smaller (which can be answered via comment easily) then ask them via comment. Otherwise there is no issue in asking another question. :)

Comment: In my case the second question is closely related to original one, but the answer is probably greater then answer to original one, so it can't be answered via comment, which has limited text.
Is it allowed to add new answer to the question, which was added as comment under original question?
Otherwise there is only one way - to add new question in separate thread.
Thanks for clearing me your rules. I'm coming from other newsgroup which has different rules and they became also my habit :)

Comment: @Simon - In your case you should ask the separate question. Since you are new you should check [FAQ] and [about] section.

Comment: @Simon - That's why Meta Stack Overflow is here. Also to reply anyone use `@` sign instead of double inverted comma (`"`).

Comment: @hims056 - i have read the FAQ but I didn't find anything about:
- edit question and expand it with some subquestions when already some members answered (that will create confusion)

- is it allowed to add new answer to some comment(which is in fact another related question) under original question
(since answering with comment has limited characters)

The rules here are quite specific and even after reading the FAQ I wanted to clear some of them.  And as suggested I asked on meta support. Thanks - in the future i'll try to follow the rules and also try to contribute for better experience.

Comment: @Simon - You are asking me the same question trice or forth time now. In about section read *Improve posts by editing or commenting*.